# Replace dynamic keyword from HTML content using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

```
<div class="fotorama__stage__frame magnify-wheel-loaded fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img fotorama__active" aria-hidden="false" data-active="true" style="left: 0px;" href="https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png">
<img src="https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png" class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false"></div>
```

I want to replace `/cache/713229083fb198/` from IMG attribute and load that image again.

From

```
https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png
```

to

```
https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/h/a/123.png
```

I want to replace it using jQuery.

Comment: will it always be that value that you're replacing?

Comment: Replacing part of a string is a string manipulation, not a jQuery operation.

Comment: @treyBake yes 713229083... Will be dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.attr( function )` to changing `src` attribute of image. In function use regex in `.replace()` to matching target part of string.

```js
$(".fotorama__img").attr("src", function(i, src){  
  return src.replace(/\/cache\/[^\/]+/, "");
});
console.log($(".fotorama__img").attr("src"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png" class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false">
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you replace it with a regex that looks for any number and lowercase character for the random looking part.

```js
var img = document.querySelector(".fotorama__img");
var src = img.src;
img.src = src.replace(/cache\/[0-9a-z]+\//, '');
console.log(img.src);
```

```html
<div class="fotorama__stage__frame magnify-wheel-loaded fotorama_vertical_ratio fotorama__loaded fotorama__loaded--img fotorama__active" aria-hidden="false" data-active="true" style="left: 0px;" href="https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png">
<img src="https://static.domain.com/media/catalog/product/cache/713229083fb198/h/a/123.png" class="fotorama__img" aria-hidden="false"></div>
```